# Pitch/chord tracking software (such as Melodyne)

Tags: software

Aside from Melodyne, do you know any other music transcription softwares Specifically those that can do, onset detection, pitch detection, possibly chord detection, and possibly tempo estimation.

I need it for some benchmarking observations.

Thanks!

I've done a basic Google search already, but I want to know which are the most popular and most convincing since I've heard a lot about Melodyne from here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MIDI, you should check out ScoreCleaner from [DoReMIR](http://www.doremir.com/). The developers are pretty enthusiastic about the possibilites of their own software (it detects key signature, time signature, tempo, voices, and rhythm & note values). However, since it new, it hasn't received that much attention yet.

You can check out some tutorials of it on Youtube (the first of them is posted below) or download a 14 day trial version on their homepage.

Answer (score -1):

I have been looking for a simple pitch tracking system such as that previously put out by Wildcat Canyon Software (AutoScore) and haven't been able to find one. Perhaps the 'Score Cleaner' by DoReMIR will be it - I'll certainly try it. One thing that puzzles me about the now defunct 'Autoscore' - I have it loaded on my computer but it wont run - I can understand that upgrades, mods, etc., wouldn't be available . . .but how does my Autoscore copy know that Wildcat Canyon has gone belly up??
Any thoughts much appreciated.
Phil

Comment: hi this is not really an answer, if you have a question please delete this comment and submit a question. thab